# WCF Web Service and TPL Task.Run

Tags: wcf, task-parallel-library

Suppose I have a method, which does not require a response, for example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFTestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ReceiveSomeData(MyDto someDtoObj);

}
```

Now, inside the actual service implementation, I can write:

```
public void ReceiveSomeData(MyDto receivedRequest)
{
    Task.Run( () => OtherProjectOtherClass.DoWhateverYouWant(receivedRequest) )
    
    //... because I am outta here as fast as possible
}
```

I assume the caller will get a 200-OK all the time; Note also that I have not written any task async/await inside the WCF method itself.

Is it acceptable to use TPL inside WCF this way, any gotchas?

*Note*: I am not concerned with business rules, I am more concerned whether it is technically acceptable for WCF/TPL to interact this way, will I run into (technical) trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you have to take in consideration.

1. Callers won't be notitified when the task is actually completed, and if it does, whether it did so with a failure (an unhandled exception for example) or not.
2. When the process hosting the service stops, your tasks may not be completed yet and unless you keep a reference to them you won't be able to wait for them to finish.
3. If an unhandled exception occurs in `OtherProjectOtherClass.DoWhateverYouWant(receivedRequest)` you won't be signalled. So make sure the whole body is contained in a try..catch and apply some logging or take other measures.
4. If a lot of requests are made and the tasks take a long time to complete you can run out of threads in the threadpool. If so, use a dedicated thread as `Task.Run` grabs one from the pool.

I do wonder, what is happening inside `OtherProjectOtherClass.DoWhateverYouWant(receivedRequest)`? Is it CPU intensive or more I/O related? If it is I/O intensive, rewrite it to a Task based method instead of using `Task.Run`.

I can't tell if these issues are really problems for you but keep it in mind.

Comment: Actually "nothing much" is happening insideDoWhateverYouWant(). Just logging to a database, firing off an Acknowledment to the caller (to a service at their end), and dealing with the request later. But thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I didn't think about #2, if the process hosting the service stops, the (child) task will stop too - but that is no different than if I did not have a Task, and all the code was inside the WCF method, it would also stop.

Comment: Normal when the Service host is ending gracefully the close method is called and pending requests are waited for, that won't happen with tasks that way.